# Maxima solve function find no solution

Tags: system, equation, solver, maxima

I am new to Maxima.

If I do:

```
solve([x = 2, y = 3], [x, y]);
```

I get:

```
 [[x = 2, y = 3]]
```

Which is correct !

If I do:

```
solve([sin(x) = 1], [x]);
```

I get:

```
         %pi
      [x = ---]
          2
```

Which is also correct !

But if I do:

```
solve([sin(x) = 1, y = 3], [x, y]);
```

I get:

```
   []
```

Why ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After `load(to_poly_solve);` try

```
to_poly_solve([sin(x)= 1, y = 3], [x,y]);
```